# Show that the Cross Ratio depends on $\lambda$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, field-theory, projective-geometry

I am trying to prove that the cross-ratio of the lines over a field $K$ defined by
$\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} \lambda \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ is dependent of $\lambda\in K$ as a way to show that there is infinitely many quadruplets of lines which are not isomorphic to these 4 lines, since the cross-ratio is invariant under isomorphisms. The problem is that i don't understand how to get around to doing this.

Comment: How is the cross-ratio defined here?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but i think it is defined as the cross ratio of 4 points of intersection with a line not going through the intersection(in this case the origin) of the 4 other lines. If that makes sense.

Comment: Ok. Can you calculate the above cross-ratio? I guess you should get $\lambda$ or $1/\lambda$.

Comment: I will try to do that. It is just if there was an easier way. But thank you :)